# NodeMailer net::ERROR_CONNECTION_RESET 400 When Trying To Send DataUri Attachment

Tags: javascript, jspdf, nodemailer

I'm getting a `datauri` when generating a PDF within my application.  After that is complete I want to send it as an attachment via email.  I saw that `nodemailer` has an option to send a `datauri` as an attachment, and luckily for me `jsPDF` has a way of getting that data.  Unfortunately for me when I go to send the email with the PDF attachment I receive this error:
`net::ERROR_CONNECTION_RESET 400 (Bad Request)`

I'm able to send other emails just fine, but when I try and send an attachment with a `datauri` this error pops up every time and the email fails to send.  I'm not sure if it's because the `datauri` is too large to send... in this case it's only `425kB` in size.

Here is how I'm generating and passing the data to the API:

```
 AcceptContract(){
        let curr = this.state.CurrentContract;
        let stores = this.state.StoresSelected;
        let list = this.state.PDFs;

        if(this.state.CurrentContract <= this.state.TotalContracts){
            if(this.state.CurrentContract != this.state.TotalContracts){
                curr++
            }

            stores[this.state.CurrentContract - 1].ContractStatus = "ACCEPTED"
           this.GeneratePDF(function(result){
                list.push(result);
                this.setState({
                    CurrentContract: curr,
                    StoresSelected: stores,
                    PDFs: list,
                })
           }.bind(this));


        }else if(this.state.CurrentContract == this.state.TotalContracts){
            console.log('render final button')
        }
    }

    GeneratePDF(callback){
        let filename = 'test.pdf'
        let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        let pdfList = this.state.PDFs;
        let data;

        html2canvas(document.getElementById('inner-container')).then(canvas => {
            data = pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'), 'JPEG', 0, 0, 211, 298).output('datauri');

            let obj = {
                path: data,
            }

            callback(obj);
        });

    }

    SendRawEmail(){
        let to = 'myeemail@email.com'; // change to accounting email
        let text = 'this is a test'
        let data = this.state.PDFs;
        console.log(data);

        $.get("/sendRaw", { to: to, subject: 'Contract Testing', text: text, data: data }, function (data) { }); 
    }
```

`this.state.PDFs` is just an empty array until a contract is accepted.

Here is the API:

```
app.get('/sendRaw', (request, response) => {

    var mailOptions = {
      to: request.query.to,
      bcc: request.query.bcc,
      subject: request.query.subject,
      text: request.query.text,
      attachment: request.query.data
    }

    smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
        from: "myemail@email.com", // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using Gmail.
        to: mailOptions.to, 
        bcc: "myemail@email.com",    // sending to itself
        subject: mailOptions.subject, // subject
        html: mailOptions.text, // body
        attachments: mailOptions.attachment,
      }, function (error, response) {  //callback
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent");
            response.send(200);
        }

        smtpTransport.close();
      });

  })
```

I'm really stumped on this one.  I can't find anyone with a similar issue online so it's even harder for me to solve it myself.  If anyone has any ideas or suggestions about why this would be failing, that would be great.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

I can send regular emails just fine without attachments, but the weird thing is that I can send a blank PDF without any errors.  As soon as I get a valid `datauri` that's when I receive this error.

Comment: A connection-reset error usually indicates the process on the other end of the connection crashed.  Is the connection-reset error being caused when the front-end calls the API, or when the API calls `smtpTransport.sendMail`?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I'm not exactly sure, but my guess would be when the API calls ```smtpTransport.sendMail```, becuase that is where I have error handling.